# Como organizar itens de um array em ordem alfabetica?

Tags: php, array

Estou com muita dificuldade de como organizar esse meu array:

```
$array = [];

$array[
        "T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama",
        "T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
        "T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
        "T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd"
      ];
```

Cada palavra de um item significa algo. Por exemplo no item:`T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz`

`T3497012` é o id do usuário. `CHOSTBRHDDSB` é um host, `EICM_BORA` é um sistema, `BPHS` é um tipo e `Bamz` é uma camada.

> Eu preciso ordenar todos os itens desse array por ordem alfabética,
>   porem existe alguns critérios:

ordem alfabética primeiro nos **sistemas** resultando o array assim:

```
"T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd",
"T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
"T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
"T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama"
```

Primeiro o sistema `AICM_BORA` e por ultimo o `EICM_BORA`

Depois preciso colocar em ordem com base no **tipo**, ficando assim:

```
"T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd",
"T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
"T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama",
"T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama"
```

Agora faço o mesmo processo e ordeno por **camada**:

```
"T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd",
"T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
"T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama",
"T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz"
```

e por ultimo por **hostname**:

```
"T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd",
"T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
"T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama",
"T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",    
"T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
"T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz"
```

tentei muitas coisas mas acredito que minha falta de experiencia não me permita uma solução pra isto.

Comment: Mas quer fazer uma ordenação com base em 4 critérios ou 4 ordenações diferentes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se cada bloco entre `@` do item significa algo então é mais fácil começar por separar esses elementos para um array com [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
foreach ($array as $chave => $valor){
    $array[$chave] = explode("@",$valor);
}
```

Que lhe irá dar um array com o seguinte aspeto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => T3497012
            [1] => CHOSTBRHDDSB
            [2] => EICM_BORA
            [3] => BPHS
            [4] => Bamz
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => T3497012
            [1] => BHOSTBRHDDSB
            [2] => EICM_BORA
            [3] => BPHS
            [4] => Bamz
        )
    ...
```

Agora que tem cada parte separada pode fazer a ordenação utilizando [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) que lhe permite especificar a forma como é ordenado através de uma função de comparação dos elementos:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]){ //posição 2 é o sistema
        if ($a[3] == $b[3]){ //posição 3 é tipo
            if ($a[4] == $b[4]){ //posição 4 é a camada
                return strcmp($a[1], $b[1]); //posição 1 é hostname
            }
            else return strcmp($a[4], $b[4]);
        }
        else return strcmp($a[3], $b[3]);
    }
    else  return strcmp($a[2], $b[2]);     
});
```

Note que a comparação das strings foi feita à custa da função [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

Agora para voltar a ficar com a `string` que tinha tanto pode juntar cada elemento numa string quando precisa de usar ou até mesmo voltar a construir o array que tinha com [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
foreach($array as $chave => $valor){
    $array[$chave] = implode("@", $array[$chave]);
}
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ul9E9O)

Que dá o seguinte resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd
    [1] => T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc
    [2] => T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb
    [3] => T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz
    [4] => T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz
    [5] => T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz
    [6] => T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama
    [7] => T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama
)
```

Diferente do que tinha indicado certo ? Mas este é o resultado correto para a ordenação nos `4` critérios que indicou. Vamos tentar perceber melhor como funcionou.

O primeiro critério é aplicado sobre o sistema, os `AICM`, `EICM`, etc. Se reparar eles estão ordenados, com especial relevância para o facto do `EICM_BORC` vir depois de `EICM_BORB` e depois de `EICM_BORA` devido à ultima letra.

Depois de ser aplicada a ordenação pelo sistema vamos aplicar a ordenação pelo tipo **apenas para os que tem o mesmo sistema** os, `3` `EICM_BORA`. Neste caso eles tem todos o mesmo tipo `BPHS`, logo passamos a aplicar a ordenação pela camada. Sendo a camada também igual nos `3` passamos ao ultimo critério de ordenação o `hostname` que é de facto diferente. Logo os `3` `EICM_BORA` acabaram ordenados pelo `hostname`.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, somente queria entender o porque ele começou por normal em sistema e depois o restante ele fez ao contrario, começou do b para o a

Comment: @JulioHenrique Qual é que comecou do b para o a ? os tipos dos  `EICM` ?

Comment: sim, os tipos do eicm

Comment: @JulioHenrique Acontece que a primeira ordenação é pelo sistema, logo os `EICM` vão para baixo, no entanto, atente que `EICM_BORC` vem depois de `EICM_BORB` e depois de `EICM_BORA` devido à ultima letra. A segunda ordenação só vai ser aplicada para todos os elementos que têm o mesmo sistema, que são os de `EICM_BORA`, `3` no total. Esses vão agora ter outra ordenação aplicada, todos os outros mantem-se na posição em que estão. E nesses `3` tanto o tipo como a camada são iguais logo prevalece a ordenação pelo `hostname`

Comment: hum verdade, me desculpa nao me atentei no final dos nomes de sistema, muito obrigado Isac você me ajudou muito

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Fiz para a camada:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    return (substr($a, 37, 4) < substr($b, 37, 4)) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = [
        "T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama",
        "T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
        "T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
        "T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd"
      ];
usort($array, "cmp");

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Sorting.php).

Se estiver usando uma versão mais recente pode que não precise passar o nome da função e sim passar a própria diretamente, o que pode ser mais interessante. Tem exemplo na documentação. Inclusive provavelmente dá para parametrizar a coluna inicial e final fazendo assim sem precisar criar uma função para cada chave usada.

Tem algumas alternativas, mas todas que pensei me parecem piores que esta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer dois `for` para varrer seu `array` e colocar os `if` na ordem dos seus critérios:

```
<?php
    $linhas = array(
        "T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama",
        "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama",
        "T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb",
        "T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc",
        "T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd"
    );

    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < (count($linhas) - 1); $i++){
        $linhai = explode("@", $linhas[$i]);
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($linhas); $j++){
            $linhaj = explode("@", $linhas[$j]);

            $troca = false;
            if ($linhai[2] > $linhaj[2])
                $troca = true;
            else if (($linhai[2] == $linhaj[2]) && ($linhai[3] > $linhaj[3]))
                $troca = true;
            else if (($linhai[2] == $linhaj[2]) && ($linhai[3] == $linhaj[3]) && ($linhai[4] > $linhaj[4]))
                $troca = true;
            else if (($linhai[2] == $linhaj[2]) && ($linhai[3] == $linhaj[3]) && ($linhai[4] == $linhaj[4]) && ($linhai[1] > $linhaj[1]))
                $troca = true;

            if ($troca){
                $suporte = $linhas[$i];
                $linhas[$i] = $linhas[$j];
                $linhas[$j] = $suporte;
            }    
        }
    }

    var_dump($linhas);
?>
```

**Saída:**

> array(8) {
>   [0]=>   string(41)  "T5557012@FHOSTBRHDDSB@AICM_BORF@APHS@camd"
>   [1]=>   string(41)  "T2497123@EHOSTBRHDDSB@BICM_BORE@APHS@camc"
>   [2]=>   string(41)  "T2497123@DHOSTBRHDDSB@CICM_BORD@APHS@camb"
>   [3]=>   string(41)  "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz"
>   [4]=>   string(41)  "T3497012@BHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz"
>   [5]=>   string(41)  "T3497012@CHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORA@BPHS@Bamz"
>   [6]=>   string(41)  "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORB@BPHS@Aama"
>   [7]=>   string(41)  "T3497012@AHOSTBRHDDSB@EICM_BORC@APHS@cama"
>   }

[Veja funcionando](https://ideone.com/SMkqKC)

Comment: Roberto muito obrigado pela resposta, mas o resultado está diferente do que eu quero, olhe na minha pergunta.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, agora esta tudo em ordem alfabetica